# Another way to say "I have started to lose hope"

Tags: phrase-requests

I have the idea of being on the verge of losing hope, and I am interested to put it in following structure: "My hopes for achieving something are getting (or growing) weaker every second."

I have googled this sentence but apparently this is not common wording for conveying the idea. Is there a similar way to say this?

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with your original *I have started to lose hope* or *I am on the verge of losing hope.* Why does it not serve your purpose? It's more natural and common than your alternative.

Comment: Yeah I see that. It's just finding a proper equivalent for a similar sentence from my native language. Maybe, it is just an absurd attempt!!

Comment: *Literal* (word for word) translations from one language to another very often end up as either awkward or outright wrong. In this case, if you want to sound idiomatic, your original version sounds better than any variation.

Comment: @mhmdadb As a general rule, **all** useful information like your comment here should appear in the question. However, this should actually be tagged [phrase-request] and we have [a lot of help with asking that sort of question](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info).

Comment: ‘Upon waking, he realized he was in the same frustrated and **despairing** state once again.’  (Showing the loss of all hope.)  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/despairing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"My level of confidence that XXX will be achieved is low, very low."

Answer (score 1):

I think the following idiomatic expression can be used in this context.

> [Not have a hope in hell](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-have-a-hope-in-hell?topic=not-hopeful) : to have no possibility of doing and
>   achieving something

Your sentence can be rephrased as:

*I don't have a hope in hell of achieving* (something).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am looking for something that expresses more of a transition or slowing losing hope rather than complete hopelessness.
By the way, the idiom you mentioned which I didn't know about before sounds very interesting